# Removing parent node from xml collections

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get rid of the parent node of a collection in xml (using linq-to-xml):

For example, the input xml:

```
<envelop>
<books>
    <book>
       <title>ABC</title>
       <publishedDate>2012-12-12</publishedDate>
       <authors>
           <author>John Smith</author>
           <author>Bob Doe</author>
       </authors>
    <book>
    <book>
       <title>XYZ</title>
       <publishedDate>2013-03-06</publishedDate>
       <authors>
           <author>Henry Blah</author>
           <author>Bob Doe</author>
       </authors>
    <book>
</books>
</envelop>
```

I would like the result to be:

```
<envelop>

    <book>
       <title>ABC</title>
       <publishedDate>2012-12-12</publishedDate>
       <author>John Smith</author>
       <author>Bob Doe</author>
    <book>
    <book>
       <title>XYZ</title>
       <publishedDate>2013-03-06</publishedDate>
       <author>Henry Blah</author>
       <author>Bob Doe</author>
    <book>
</envelop>
```

The nodes: `<books>` and `<authors>` are gone - only their children remain.

I saw the following question but with XSLT ([Remove parent nodes from xml with xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444726/remove-parent-nodes-from-xml-with-xslt)). Would like to stay away from XSLT at the moment.

Comment: If books is the root element and and you want the output to be XML then I don't think you can.

Comment: I look like somebody tried to serialize the xml and ended up with two layers of tags for the arrays.  It would be simpler to fix the xml serialize by adding [XmlElement()] before the arrays to get only one tag instead of the two tags.  Looks like you are just doing a kludge instead of fixing root cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var document = XDocument.Load(validXmlFilePath);
        while (document.Descendants("authors").Any())
        {
            var x = document.Descendants("authors").First();
            x.AddAfterSelf(x.Nodes());
            x.Remove();
        }
        var result = document.Descendants("book");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you fill your object in code and than serialize it? If so, you can use **[XmlElement("Book")]** attribute above your list property in your class:

```
[XmlElement("Book")]    
public List<Book> Books {get; set;}
```

Answer (score -1):

In VB the code would be

```
    Dim result As XElement = <envelop></envelop>

    result.Add(xe...<book>)

    For Each el As XElement In result...<author>.ToList
        el.Parent.Parent.Add(New XElement(el))
    Next

    result...<authors>.Remove()
```

with xe defined as

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'to load from a file
    '  xe = XElement.Load("Your Path Here")

    ' for testing
    xe = <envelop>
             <books>
                 <book>
                     <title>ABC</title>
                     <publishedDate>2012-12-12</publishedDate>
                     <authors>
                         <author>John Smith</author>
                         <author>Bob Doe</author>
                     </authors>
                 </book>
                 <book>
                     <title>XYZ</title>
                     <publishedDate>2013-03-06</publishedDate>
                     <authors>
                         <author>Henry Blah</author>
                         <author>Bob Doe</author>
                     </authors>
                 </book>
             </books>
         </envelop>
```

result looks like

```
<envelop>
  <book>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <publishedDate>2012-12-12</publishedDate>
    <author>John Smith</author>
    <author>Bob Doe</author>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>XYZ</title>
    <publishedDate>2013-03-06</publishedDate>
    <author>Henry Blah</author>
    <author>Bob Doe</author>
  </book>
</envelop>
```